# How to find a difference between two BLOB values in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have two tables in my mysql db.

Each table has a column of BLOB datatype.

Can you please help me to identify any method to find the difference between two blob columns.

In layman's query language, something like:

```
select a.blob_column
     ,a.id
     ,b.blob_column 
     ,b.id 
  from table1
     ,table2 
 where a.id=b.id 
   and blob_compare (a.blob_column,b.blob_column)!=0
```

I know the above query is on own terms , but hope you got the picture on what i was expecting.

Eg:

table 1

```
 id | Blob_value
----------------------------
1  | quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
2  | An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
```

table 2

```
id | Blob_value
----------------------------
1  | quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
2  | You are awesome.
```

Now when i query i need the result such as:

```
2 | An apple a day keeps the doctor away | 2  | You are awesome.
```

As you can see i need the values which the blob values are different.

In oracle there are some ways to find like dbms_lob.compare, Can you please help me for the same in MYSQL.

Note:My table is used in DWH and it contains 2 milliion records.If there are any ways in python coding to is appreciated.Just in case if the result in mysql cant be done.

Comment: sorry for the titile its actually a BLOB..BLOB is a datatype in mysql or any query languages

Comment: @Strawberry: got it thank you. Now please help me with the solution

Comment: These don't look like blobs; they look like short strings of text

Comment: its an example ..i cant type all my PII credential data which is of JSON type. Is there any way to compare a BLOB data?

Comment: The point is that the tools we would use for a short string differ from those we would use for a blob

Comment: i dont need a tool.Is there a command either in mysql or python to fix my issue. I need to do the automation to check the BLOB difference on daily basis